# Swift 4 back from Subview

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview, subview

I want to make **Back** button from mySubView. I have payment ViewController with button, this button make view.addSubview(WkWebView). So i can open WkWebView but i have no possibility to lose it.

My code:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
self.wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.wkWebView.frame =  CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.wkWebView.frame.size.width, height: self.wkWebView.frame.size.height)
self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)

loadUrl()

func loadUrl(){
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://ecg.test.upc.ua/go/enter")
    var myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    wkWebView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
let back = UIButton(type: .system)

back.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 100, height: 50)

back.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)

back.sizeToFit()

back.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.back), for: .touchUpInside)

wkWebView.addSubview(back)
```

//

```
@objc func back() { 

    wkWebView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

//

also give a frame to the `wkWebView` in a relation to the superView , and don't set `self.wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` as it's when you add constraints

```
self.wkWebView.frame = self.view.framw
```

Comment: yes , make sure to do everything mentioned in answer

Comment: i see the button but one more question... my button appears right on my WkWebView, how i can make space on top on view for my back button?

Comment: increase y for the frame line